# Yii2 Signup Email option

Tags: email, yii2

How can I set up automatic email for signup activation link in yii 2.0.3 advanced application template and how link back to login page
in this new version?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Swiftmailer in `common\config\main.php components` array:

// for sending mail using swift mailer

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class'         => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host'          => 'your_host_name',
                'username'      => 'enter_your_username_here',
                'password'      => 'enter_your_password',
                'port'          => '25',
            ],

        ],
```

After this you can use the following code to send mails:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contact/html', ['contactForm' => $form])
    ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
    ->setTo($form->email)
    ->setSubject($form->subject)
    ->send();
```

`contact/html` is the template name which is there is **common/mail** folder and `contactForm` variable having value `$form` is passed to that template.

You can put the above code in your controller. But I will suggest make a commonfunction of it and use it from anywhere. Hope it helps.

Comment: Then what about controller?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.